# ASP.NET Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following 80080005

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, interop

I am building an ASP.Net site that constructs docx files.  I'm attempting to convert them to pdfs using the Interop libraries.  I'm aware that it's not the best or most efficient method, but it's the method I have available.

I have Word installed on the server running my site.  Running the site that converts the file in my development environment works fine (that's my main pc with Office installed).  The server has had Word installed, however attempting the conversion on the server generates the error in the title.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following 80080005.

In the C# code itself, the line that fails is the line that declares and iniates the ApplicationClass.

```
ApplicationClass l_WA_wordApplication = new ApplicationClass();
```

I have been looking at this for some time and here are the fixes I have so far verified or attempted:

- The site is configured to compile to "Any CPU"
- The server does not have Word listed in DCOM.  Attempting to run "Winword.exe -regserver" in a command prompt starts Word and prompts that it is not registered.  This may be the cause and we are currently investigating.  Keep in mind, though, that I built a small executable that I ran on the server using the same conversion code, and it worked correctly.
- I have granted access to the actual WinWord.exe file to the IIS_IUSRS user.

I know there may be some information that I am lacking in this question, so please let me know if you have any questions about my setup.

Comment: Does your IIS AppPool's bitness match the bitness of Word that you installed? That is, if your AppPool is set to run x64, do you have x64 office installed?

Comment: Word does not support ASP.Net (nobody can click a message box in a service session). Besides Word is STA and ASP.Net is MTA.

Comment: The version of Word installed on the server is 32-bit, installed on a 64-bit OS.  The App Pool has "Enable 32-Bit Applications" set to True. As for MTA vs STA, or Word not supporting ASP.Net, I've known this isn't the most efficient method, but does that mean it isn't possible?